# How to set "limited" security access in Filemaker for a related table using PHP access

Tags: php, security, filemaker

I am accessing Filemaker tables through PHP

In Filemaker I want to limit access to records in table A

Table A has two fields: Login Name and Group ID

For Table A, I set the record level security to “limited” and the (Records can be viewed when) condition to: “get(AccountName) = Login Name”
This works well.

Table B has two fields: Group ID and Group Name

Now I want to set the access for records in Table B where Table A::Group ID = Table B::Group ID

How do I set the "limited" Boolean condition for Table B?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I called and paid for tech support with Filemaker.  They answered my question in an unexpected way but it works for my solution:
http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/d47c9785a2?commentId=297384

Answer (score 0):

It would be using FileMaker' standard security model.  Go to the file menu in FM > Security and set field level restrictions to the user there.  It should propagate to PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I am very familiar with the security settings except in the case I outlined above.  I need a specific boolean phrase like:  (Get ( AccountName ) = Table A::Login) and (Table A::Group ID  = Table B::GroupID)

Comment: It turns out this is a problem, independent of PHP.  If there are two records in Table A, Login Name UserA and UserB

Comment: If there are two records in Table A, 
Record 1 Login Name = “ UserA”, Group ID = “1”
And 
Record 2 Login Name = “UserB”, Group ID = “1”

And there is 1 record in Table B (Group ID = “1”)

If I log in as “UserA” then the record in Table B is visible
If I log in as “UserB” then the record in Table B is not visible (“<No Access>”)

Comment: Sounds like you have to repeat the data and keep UserA and UserB also stored in TableB

Comment: Each record in Table A represents a member in a group (members can be members of multiple Groups.  Each record in table B represents a Group.  So I cannot store the member information for each member on the Table B group record.  Also, this is a simplified example of my actual problem, where members need access to 14 different related tables (tables related but do not store the members AccountName.